# Prompt to allow ssh connection on server

Tags: server, ssh, openssh

I have installed `openssh-server` on a Laptop of a friend to help him out from remote.  
I don't want to have always the possibility to login to his computer without him knowing.

So what could I do, so he needs first to allow me access to his computer each time? 
I would like to have something like, that a prompt pops up on his computer, where he can just click *allow connection* or *not allow connection*

Comment: not, TeamViewer is no alternative :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your friend trust you, but would like to control when you'll login his computer, I can suggest the following:

- Provide your friend a simple explanation how to `start` / `stop` the `openssh` server
- Add a unique user for you, which he will allow access (by changing `shell` or by changing the `password` to a known pre-defined password)

Using one of the above two simple method will allow your friend to enable/disable the ability login into his laptop by himself.

The trigger to enable/disable access might be a phone call / SMS / etc.

Comment: ok, I think I will set it off by default and then add a button with a little bash script on the desktop. Can you say, how to turn openssh server off by default? Normally it always starts with startup

Comment: systemctl disable ssh

Answer (score 0):

You can use /etc/ssh/sshrc to run commands when someone logs in including ones that are blocking.  If you want to simply notify the other person of your presence, the script could be used to send an email or SMS.  If you are certain you want to prompt you could do something like this:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
notify-send 'Alert' "User $USER just logged in from $ip"

if zenity --question --text="User $USER just logged in from $ip, Is this OK?" --ok-label=Yes --cancel-label=No
then
    echo Access Granted
else
    echo Access Denied
    sleep infinity
fi
```

This will work if the friend has run

```
xhost +localhost
```

I'm not sure how to force the user to logout, hence the sleep infinity.  When the user Ctrl-C, it kills the ssh connection.